# Qt and Keypad Integration

Tags: qt

In my project I will use a button group (10 buttons) for input (keyboard) and Windows Embedded.  I want to use qt for gui and each buttons in the group have special tasks just like cell phone's key pad.

How can I use functions or classes in qt which are for normal keyboard?

Comment: Could you expand your question please, it's not too clear at the moment.

Comment: it will be a system with joystick and console.The whole system will communicate with CAN bus and i want to use Windows Embedded as an operating system and qt for GUI.In the normal computer environment,i can use qt's functions easily but how can i create a click signal when i press a button in the console or write somethings to a line with my console which have only 10 buttons ???